# Column count doesn't match value count in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Whenever I am trying to insert data in table:

```
INSERT INTO `operator`(`id`, `operator_name`, `email`, `info`)
VALUES (1,'Bangalink','This is all about Banglalink'),
(2, 'Robi', 'This is all about Robi');
```

MySQL said:#1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

How can i fix it?
I don't understand what need to do.
TIA

Comment: And does it?...

Comment: You have 4 fieldnames and only 3 data

Comment: sorry its actually three field..now i edited it.

Comment: I Think so. Should i remove it

Comment: @Arman - I've rolled it back. Please don't make such changes to the question, such that the answer(s) become redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The provided number of columns in the column list specification and number of column values in each record must match.

Assuming you don't want to insert email data, remove that from the column list:

```
INSERT INTO `operator`(`id`, `operator_name`, `info`)
VALUES (1,'Bangalink','This is all about Banglalink'),
(2, 'Robi', 'This is all about Robi');
```

or pass null for email:

```
INSERT INTO `operator`(`id`, `operator_name`, `email`, `info`)
VALUES (1,'Bangalink',null,'This is all about Banglalink'),
(2, 'Robi', null,'This is all about Robi');
```

Second method is useful when you may have emails for few records.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion .

Answer (score 0):

You pass one item - `info`:

```
INSERT INTO `operator`(`id`, `operator_name`, `email`, `info`)
VALUES (1,'Bangalink','This is all about Banglalink', NULL),
(2, 'Robi', 'This is all about Robi',NULL);
```

or

```
INSERT INTO `operator`(`id`, `operator_name`, `email`)
VALUES (1,'Bangalink','This is all about Banglalink'),
(2, 'Robi', 'This is all about Robi');
```

Comment: sorry i didn't check correctly. but thanks for remind me that there is four column i am taking but i gave 3 value.